# Can i bind the OK button in the first panel to a function that runs and check if the correct id as been ennter and if correct the next panel appears

Tags: wxpython

```
import wx
class MainFrame (wx.Frame):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 800,600 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
    def __del__( self ):
        pass
class first_panel ( wx.Panel ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 800,600 ), style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        greetings = wx.StaticText(self, label='Welcome to 24-hour ATM service')
        sizer.Add(greetings, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=15)
        line = wx.StaticLine(self)
        sizer.Add(line, pos=(1, 0), span=(1, 5), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        customerIdText = wx.StaticText(self, label="Customer Id")
        sizer.Add(customerIdText, pos=(3, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        customerIdInput = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        sizer.Add(customerIdInput, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        okButton = wx.Button(self, label="Ok")
        sizer.Add(okButton, pos=(4, 3), span=(1, 1))
        okButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOkClicked)
        cancelButton = wx.Button(self, label="Cancel")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use multiple classes or perform the task within a single class.
As the process seems to be sequential, it may be easier, to begin with, to do it all in a single class.
Hopefully, you are looking for something like this.

```
import wx

choices=["Withdraw Cash","Make a deposit","Check Balance"]

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(750,-1))
        self.Customer_panel()
        self.Show()

    def Customer_panel(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Customer Id:")
        sizer.Add(text, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.customer_id = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel)
        sizer.Add(self.customer_id, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        next = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Login")
        sizer.Add(next, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        next.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnNext_1)
        self.customer_id.SetFocus()

    def OnNext_1(self, event):
        self.CustId = self.customer_id.GetValue()
        if self.CustId != "1442":
            wx.MessageBox("Incorrect Customer Id","Error", wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
            self.customer_id.SetValue('')
            self.customer_id.SetFocus()
            return
        self.panel.Destroy()
        self.Transaction_type_panel()

    def Transaction_type_panel(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Customer Id: "+str(self.CustId))
        sizer.Add(text, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.trans_type = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, -1, "Transaction type", choices=choices)
        sizer.Add(self.trans_type, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        next = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Next")
        sizer.Add(next, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        back = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Back")
        sizer.Add(back, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        exit = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Exit")
        sizer.Add(exit, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        next.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnNext_2)
        back.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBack_2)
        exit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit_2)
        self.trans_type.SetSelection(0)

    def OnNext_2(self, event):
        self.Type = self.trans_type.GetSelection()
        self.panel.Destroy()
        self.Transaction_panel()

    def OnBack_2(self, event):
        self.panel.Destroy()
        self.Customer_panel()

    def OnExit_2(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def Transaction_panel(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Customer Id: "+str(self.CustId))
        sizer.Add(text, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        text2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="You chose to "+choices[self.Type])
        sizer.Add(text2, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        exit = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Exit")
        sizer.Add(exit, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        back = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Back")
        sizer.Add(back, 0, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        exit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit_3)
        back.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBack_3)

    def OnExit_3(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def OnBack_3(self, event):
        self.panel.Destroy()
        self.Transaction_type_panel()

app = wx.App()
Example(None, title='Sequential Panels')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @Joejoe You can accept an answer by clicking the grey tick sign beside the answer. Or if it was useful but didn't answer the question, click the up arrow. If it was downright unhelpful, click the down arrow.